# What causes my laptop to awake randomly, search and connect to WiFi Networks while suspended?

Tags: networking, suspend, security, power-management

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS still installed. When suspending the laptop, the laptop is going in and out of suspend mode.

I know it's spending most of its time suspended because the battery is lasting 2 days, and it's an old laptop--when on it only lasts about 2-4 hours depending usage.

I walk from one side of my city to another, from point A -> C. In the middle is point B. I open my laptop at point C, and it has tried to connect to WiFi network at point B, even thought it was suspended at point A and not awoken until point C. It also remembers a list of every wifi network en route from point A - > C even if suspended.

This above thing happens even if I leave the laptop suspended for a day or two.

Sometimes when I open the laptop, it's already awake. Sometimes it's asleep, but it has been scoping out wifi networks.

Well, perhaps this is some kind of bug, but it certainly makes me look paranoid!

Unfortunately I'm not security-savvy enough to know where to begin to look to see what's causing this, but at the very least it's slowly deteriorating my battery life (on the order of 100%->0 over about 4 days).

Comment: Notice the battery percentage when laptop wakes up. If I remember correctly, laptops can be set to wake up once battery reaches critical level.. That might be your case

Comment: Noticed that. It happens regardless of battery level.